# How to check whether the checkbox is checked in Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a Task class which contains a boolean attribute called 'complete', which stores the information wheter a task is completed or not.

Now in my task list, I would like to have a checkbox to change the Task.complete to True if checkbox is checked.

```
<div class="task-list-wrapper">
        {% for task in task_list %}
        <div class="task-wrapper">
            {% if task.complete %}
            <div class="task-title">
                <div class="task-complete-icon"></div>
                <i><s><a href="{% url 'task-update' task.id %}">{{task}}</a></s></i>
            </div>
            <a class="delete-link" href="{% url 'task-delete' task.id %}">&#128465</a>
            {% else %}
            <div class="task-title">
                <div class="task-incomplete-icon"></div>
                <a href="{% url 'task-update' task.id %}">{{task}}</a>
            </div>
            <a class="delete-link" href="{% url 'task-delete' task.id %}">&#128465</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% empty %}
        <h3>No items in list</h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Assuming that each 'task' in 'task_list' will have own

`<input type="checkbox" name="task-status" value="Mark as complete">`

how do I assign the task.complete = True?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    task_status = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

views.py:

```
def form_view(request):
...
form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.POST["task_status"]:
            # Condition for checked check-box
            # task.complete = True
```

Comment: and how am I supposed to apply it to my code?

Answer (score 0):

urlpattern ("url_to_your_view_fn",views.TaskUpdate)

**html**

```
<form id="xyz" action="url_to_your_view_fn" method="POST">
 <div class="task-list-wrapper"> 
...
   {% for task in task_list %}
   <input type="checkbox" name="ids" id={{task.id}} value={{task.id}}>
   
   {% endfor %}
   <button  type="submit" >update</button>
...
 <div> 
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def TaskUpdate(request, pk):  
    idlist = request.POST.getlist('ids')
        for n in idlist:
            d=taskModel.objects.get(id=n)
            d.complete=True
            d.save
    return redirect('../')
```